# How should I use the cache API with futures

Tags: scala, caching, playframework

I want to use the built in playframework cache API but not sure how to cache this web service request when it has futures.

```
def getUser(username: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
  ws.url("...").get.map { response =>
    response.json.validate[User] match {
       case JsSuccess(user, _) => Some(user)
       case JsError(errors) => {
           // log errors
           None
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The cache key will just be the username for now.

How would I use the cache API here?

I wanted to use the getOrElse pattern:

```
val user: User = cache.getOrElse[User]("item.key") {
  User.findById(connectedUser)
}
```

But the Future and Option is confusing me on how to go about using it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
def fromWebservice(username: String): Future[Option[User]] =
  ws.url("..").get.map(validate) // validate does the json validate thing

def getUser(username: String): Future[Option[User]] = 
  cache.getAs[User](username) match {
    case Some(x) =>
      Future.successful(Some(x))
    case None =>
      fromWebservice(username).map(_.map { user =>
        cache.set(username, user)
        x
      })
  }
```

As an aside, the Play cache API does not have an API that returns `Future`s, but they're working on it: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5912

Comment: shouldn't you be returning `user` in the `case None` portion of the match?